# Subset data frame and compare rows against a specified value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, df, of the form below and would like to compare the "Frequency" at Visit = C1 with each of the values at other visits for each Mutation per ID. So, for ID = A1 and TP53 H168QH, each Visit (rows 1-6) would be compared against C1 (row 2; 0.0028148).

```
head(df)
   ID Visit       Mutation Frequency
1  A1  Base    TP53 H168QH 0.4115056
2  A1    C1    TP53 H168QH 0.0028148
3  A1    C3    TP53 H168QH 0.0005448
4  A1    C5    TP53 H168QH 0.0027240
5  A1    C7    TP53 H168QH 0.0063560
6  A1    C9    TP53 H168QH 0.0023608
7  A1  Base     TP53 G266R 0.0017252
8  A1    C1     TP53 G266R 0.0071732
9  A1    C5     TP53 G266R 0.0046308
10 A1  Base     TP53 I195T 0.0968836
11 A1    C1     TP53 I195T 0.0805396
12 A1    C3     TP53 I195T 0.1301164
13 A1    C5     TP53 I195T 0.0004540
14 A1    C7     TP53 I195T 0.0025424
15 A1    C9     TP53 I195T 0.0007264
```

I have been able to make some progress with dplyr and have come across the lag function which is close to what I want but I want to select the comparator as C1 rather than comparing consecutive rows.

```
df %>% group_by(ID, Mutation) %>% 
mutate(Difference=100*(Frequency-lag(Frequency,
order_by=Mutation))/lag(Frequency, order_by=Mutation))
```

Can any one suggest a way of approaching this please?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID, Mutation) %>%mutate(Difference=100*(Frequency-Frequency[Visit=="C1"])/Frequency[Visit=="C1"])`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Since we use the value twice, I created a column with the C1 value, then use that in the calculation, then get rid of it

```
df %>% group_by(ID, Mutation) %>% 
  mutate(C1F = Frequency[Visit=="C1"], 
         Difference = 100*(Frequency-C1F)/C1F, 
         C1F = NULL)
```

Comment: That's awesome - thanks guys! So simple - it was staring me in the face despite hours trying to solve this. Many thanks!